# PInvoke in WinRT results in Error _NO_TOKEN(1008)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, pinvoke, .net-4.5

I am trying to access Battery device information (On the lines of [Enumerating Battery Devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) using PInvoke and .Net4.5. I have one WPF application working fine, and able to get all sort of low level Battery information.

Now I am trying to modify the same app to WinRT modern app. Win32 APIs such as SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces, SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail are working well inside WinRT. But when it comes to CreateFile, I am getting Invalid handle (-1) and Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() is giving 1008 (Error_No_Token). Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error().ToString() is giving "-2147023888"

Any idea how to use CreateFile via PIvoke in WinRT?

```
[DllImport ("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
      string lpFileName,
      uint dwDesiredAccess,
      uint dwShareMode,
      IntPtr SecurityAttributes,
      uint dwCreationDisposition,
      uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
      IntPtr hTemplateFile
      );

   //var hBattery = NativeMethods.CreateFile (devicePath, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, FileAttributes.Normal, IntPtr.Zero);
    var hBattery = NativeMethods.CreateFile (devicePath, 3, 3, IntPtr.Zero, 3, 128, IntPtr.Zero);
    if ( hBattery == new IntPtr (-1) )
    { throw new System.Exception(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error().ToString()); }
```

Comment: You can't call CreateFile, the sandbox doesn't allow it. For files, you must use the new windows runtime api's in the Windows.Storage namespace. For other devices, you're out of luck, unless a new api is available. Try the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.aspx namespace.

Comment: Thanks Kris. If you can put the same comment as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted answer. It actually guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea how to use CreateFile via p/invoke in WinRT?

You cannot do so. WinRT restricts which APIs user code is allowed to call, and this function is not available from WinRT. The [documentation for `CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) states the restriction as so:

> **Requirements**
>
> Minimum supported client: Windows XP [desktop apps only]
>
> Minimum supported server: Windows Server 2003 [desktop apps only]

The text *desktop apps only* means *not available from WinRT*.

On WinRT you are expected to use the imaginitively named [`CreateFile2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422.aspx). Take a look at its requirements:

> **Requirements**
>
> Minimum supported client: Windows 8 [desktop apps | Windows Store apps]
>
> Minimum supported server: Windows Server 2012 [desktop apps | Windows Store apps]

The text *Windows Store apps* means that the function is available to WinRT code.

When using WinRT, there are large amounts of the traditional Windows API that are not available. You should get into the habit of checking the requirements section of the documentation before attempting to call API functions.

Comment: Thanks Dave! I got to start reading the fine print about Store apps section more. But the restriction is not entirely true, see http://gerhas.netii.net/wordpress/?p=45 for an example. I tried CreateFile2, and got an access denied error. This time documentation is correct, "When called from a Windows Store app, CreateFile2 is simplified. You can open only files or directories inside the ApplicationData.LocalFolder or Package.InstalledLocation directories."
I think I have to go with Windows.Devices.Custom route.

Comment: I think my answer is accurate